# Chrome 'Aw, snap' error only on mobilel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, nginx, centos

I am a newbie and am developing and hosting a website for the first time. I have a rails app, running on a Centos system with Phusion passenger and nginx server. The website url is http://www.shutuplegs.in . The website is loading fine on computers, however on chrome on mobile phones am getting the 'Aw, snap' error. What might be wrong and where should I start debugging this?

My repository : https://github.com/dsmegha/shut_up_legs

Edit : I still am stuck with this weird problem and have no idea how to get this working. I have filed a bug with chrome, but that might take a lot of time to fix.

Comment: I just tried with Chrome on my iPhone and the page shows up correctly.

Comment: I could reproduce this bug on my android. But when I check `request for desktop site` option, it loads the page correctly. Maybe that's a good place to start

Comment: Thanks @RoshanJossey. Let me see what I can do.